# select returns zero rows although it should return some entries

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, rest, express

I have a postgres database representing a simple demo forum. There are two tables called

**topic**

```
id   | topic_id (the parent topic) | name | description
-------------------------------------------------------
uuid | uuid                        | text | text
```

and **thread**

```
id   | topic_id | name | created_at
-------------------------------------------------------
uuid | uuid     | text | timestamp without timezone
```

By using an Express REST API I want to get all the information for one topic. I pass in it's ID and would like to get a result like this

```
{
    parentTopic: {}, // could be null if no parent is available
    name: "",
    description: "",
    childTopics: [{}, {}, {}],
    threads: [{}, {}, {}] // should be sorted by created_at
}
```

As far as I know it is not possible to return a result like this. But I tried to create a query to get these information and maybe I can map this later on with some code.

```
SELECT
    currentTopic.name,
    currentTopic.description,
    parentTopic.id AS parentTopicId,
    parentTopic.name AS parentTopicName,
    parentTopic.description AS parentTopicDescription,
    childTopic.id AS childTopicId,
    childTopic.name AS childTopicName,
    childTopic.description AS childTopicDescription,
    linkedThread.id AS threadId,
    linkedThread.name AS threadName,
    linkedThread.created_at AS threadCreatedAt
FROM
    topic currentTopic
INNER JOIN
    topic parentTopic ON currentTopic.topic_id = parentTopic.id
INNER JOIN
    topic childTopic ON currentTopic.id = childTopic.topic_id
INNER JOIN
    thread linkedThread ON currentTopic.id = linkedThread.topic_id
WHERE
    currentTopic.id = '624aaab6-2d2d-45dc-a425-c2863f05779c'
ORDER BY
    linkedThread.created_at;
```

When executing this (I use pgAdmin) I no error occurs but I get 0 rows returned. I made sure, there should be some entries to retrieve.

Is something wrong with that query? Is there a way to improve the query to return me a result that is ready to use (the JS object I mentioned above)?

Edit:

Here is some test data for the threads and topics

Topic table:

[image]

Thread table:

[image]

Comment: share your tables data otherwise how we know why it not returning rows

Comment: The comment 'could be null if no parent is available' for parentTopic is not accurate - the query has inner joins, so without parent there will be no results.

Comment: I updated my question to provide some data from the tables

Comment: @Question3r Try if `topic` with the `where` clause output rows. Then, go one by one `inner join` to see which one is filtering out the rows

Comment: @Koen so you think it is not possible with one query?

Comment: @SNR sorry, I am new to SQL, what do you mean =?

Comment: @Question3r Try if this query output results: `select top 1 * from topic where     currentTopic.id = '624aaab6-2d2d-45dc-a425-c2863f05779c'`. If is not returning rows is because this topic is not found in the database.

Comment: @SNR I had to update your query, here is my syntax https://pastebin.com/P8iSNjdi

Comment: @Question3r Then go for each `inner join`, parent topic, child topic and linkedThread to see which one would be filering out this rows. I mean `select * from topic t inner join topic p on t.topic_id = p.id where t.id = '624aaab6-2d2d-45dc-a425-c2863f05779c' Limit 1` in case not returning rows is because one of the `inner joins` is filtering out this rows.

Comment: @Question3r sorry, I forgot `top ([N])` is not standard. Please change `top` by `Limit [N]` at the end.

Comment: @SNR I think Zaynul Abadin Tuhin provided a working solution .. I will have to test this query for multiple cases

Comment: @Question3r yes I belive `left join` suits better for this case.

Comment: using a `GROUP BY` would get me closer to the desired Javascript object format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change inner join to left join

```
SELECT
    currentTopic.name,
    currentTopic.description,
    parentTopic.id AS parentTopicId,
    parentTopic.name AS parentTopicName,
    parentTopic.description AS parentTopicDescription,
    childTopic.id AS childTopicId,
    childTopic.name AS childTopicName,
    childTopic.description AS childTopicDescription,
    linkedThread.id AS threadId,
    linkedThread.name AS threadName,
    linkedThread.created_at AS threadCreatedAt
FROM
    topic currentTopic
left JOIN
    topic parentTopic ON currentTopic.topic_id = parentTopic.id
left JOIN
    topic childTopic ON currentTopic.id = childTopic.topic_id
left JOIN
    thread linkedThread ON currentTopic.id = linkedThread.topic_id
WHERE
    currentTopic.id = '624aaab6-2d2d-45dc-a425-c2863f05779c'
ORDER BY
    linkedThread.created_at;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this works. Is there a way to change the result in a way that it comes closer to the desired javascript object format? I think `GROUP BY` would do it but I've never used it before

Comment: @Question3r  if you don't need aggregation then there is no need  group by so it is depends on your requirement